# Serialization: Will changing the underlying class be an issue?

Tags: c#, class, serialization

I am trying to wrap my head around serialization. But what happens if for whatever reasons I need to add or remove some values or properties? How will this affect the contents? Or is this not an issue? Or how can I avoid this?

Comment: It depends what serialization mechanism you are using. BinaryFormatter? XmlSerializer? Json.NET? This is a moderately complicated topic.

Comment: Oh sorry. I was using XmlSerializer for learning, then planned on moving to BinaryFormatter for SQL storage. This is more complicated than I thought, I take it?

Comment: I strongly advise you **not** to move to BinaryFormatter for SQL storage - it is not (IMO) well-suited to storage over any duration. I humbly submit protobuf-net may be a better choice (I'm the author; it is free, etc, and designed specifically to avoid many of the problems in BinaryFormatter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As people already pointed out, it depends on your serializer. `XmlSerializer` is somewhat easier to handle in this case:

1. The serializer works against the public interface, so if you change the implementation, nothing goes wrong.
2. XML is human-readable and therefore easy to parse by hand or with some XML utilities. Therefore you could write a version converter if everything else goes wrong.

Consider Jon's anwer for more tips, especially with `NonSerialized` and `OptionalField` attributes.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what serialization technique you are using and if you plan on deserializing legacy objects.

I believe you *may* run into some issues if you add or remove properties and still want to deserialize older versions of your objects, depending on what type of serialization you are doing.

For **BinaryFormatter** and **SoapFormatter**:

- If you add new properties, you will need to adorn them with the [OptionalField Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.optionalfieldattribute.aspx) so that you can still deserialize older versions of your object that don't have the new field.
- If you are "removing" properties, you will have to leave them in the code, but adorn them with the [OptionalField Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.optionalfieldattribute.aspx) so that you can still deserialize older versions of your object that still have the removed field.

Answer (score 1):

I can speak for XmlSerializer, as its used extensively in my own project.

Adding properties doesn't cause any issues with XmlSerializer, the missing properties from the serialized xml will simply keep their default value.  The effect of removing or renaming existing properties is simply data loss.  Unless you deal with the original xml AS xml, or a text file, the data in the removed or renamed properties is simply lost.  No special attributes are needed to add, remove, or rename properties when using XmlSerializer.